# Is it possible in Gremlin to select data from inner steps

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

I got a case

I need to select `node_1`, that has some edges, or select just an `node_1` by itself

```
traversal()
        .V().hasLabel("label_1")
        .has("property_key", P.within(numbers)).as("node_1")
        .or(
                __.bothE().hasLabel("label_2").dedup().as("rels").otherV().as("node_2"),
                __.constant(true)
        )
        .project("n1","r", "n2")
        .by(__.select("node_1"))
        .by(__.coalesce(__.unfold().select("rels"), __.unfold()))
        .by(__.coalesce(__.unfold().select("node_2"), __.unfold()))
        .toList()
```

But in result, when i watch the `rels`, there is a `node_1`.
And in a `node_2`, there is also a `node_1`

You can see:

[image]

I guess, it is because gremlin cant find `rels` and `node_2` in step structure

But in graph - such a vertexes and edges present

So if i write same without "or"

```
traversal()
        .V().hasLabel("label_1")
        .has("property_key", P.within(numbers)).as("node_1")
        .bothE().hasLabel("label_2").dedup().as("rels").otherV().as("node_2")
        .project("n1","r", "n2")
        .by(__.select("node_1"))
        .by(__.select("rels"))
        .by(__.select("node_2"))
        .toList()
```

I got the result

[image]

As you can see

I understand, that in first case, the `__.unfold()` is triggered, so we got the `node_1` everywhere

But how i can get `rels` or `node_2` - i cant understand

Is there any solutions to get steps from `or` step

Or maybe there is another solutions to find either

```
"node_1" + "rels" + "node_2"
```

or to find only

```
"node_1" + default_value + default_value
```

using only one query

Thanks for answer!

P.S.

Here is some text for better search in google, i use that queries when i was searching for an answer, get it from browser history:

gremlin select step from or,
gremlin select inner step,
gremlin select step,
gremlin select inner step name,
gremlin select multiply step name,
gremlin as inside or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no path inside of a filter to `select()` from:

```
gremlin> g.inject(1,2,3).as('a').or(__.is(1).as('b'),__.is(2).as('c')).path()
==>[1]
==>[2]
gremlin> g.inject(1,2,3).as('a').filter(__.is(1).as('b')).path()
==>[1]
```

You need to actually have Gremlin traverse a path for it to get added to the history. I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to do, but I think you could simplify the structure of you whole traversal to:

```
g.V().hasLabel("label_1").
  has("property_key", P.within(numbers)).
  coalesce(bothE("label_2").elementMap(),
           identity())
```

This way your conditional is handled by `coalesce()` and each edge gets returned. You can obviously replace `elementMap()` with something more robust if you need to return data on both vertices - perhaps just replace it with a `project()` variation.

Comment: Ok, i guess i nearly to understand what you are talking about, but can you please actually write a query for my case I tried use path for me but when i execute `traversal().V().hasLabel("label_1").has("property_key", P.within(numbers)).as("node_1").or(__.bothE().hasLabel("label_2").dedup().as("rels").otherV().as("node_2"), __.identity()).path().toList()` It always return only  "node_1" and "node_2" vertexes in path, but not edge. What is wrong with my query

Comment: I don't think you understand. You can't access a labelled step (i.e. the path) within a filter. That's what I was demonstrating to you in my console session. You therefore need to re-write your traversal which is what I tried to do in that traversal that used `coalesce()`.

Comment: Thanks!
I catch.

It is impossible to select inner steps.

thanks for solutioins. I will use coalesce for my code

`traversal().V().hasLabel("label_1").has("property_key", P.within(numbers)).as("node_1").coalesce(__.bothE().hasLabel("label_2"), __.identity()).as("rel_or_node_1").path().project("node_1", "rel_o_node_1").by(__.select("node_1")).by(__.select("rel_or_node_1")).toList()` And get target node - "node_2" from edge, if it return relationship "rel_or_node_1"